# how to run both codes at the same moment on two computers by one Enter or click or command

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu-16.04

I am using two codes at the same time on two computers for a robot and running them separately. they are working fine but I'd like to run both by one command instead of two. I used an idea of these codes [here](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy_tutorials/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber).

I probably want to add IP address, if YES, please help.

if I assume those codes:
code1.py on computer 1, IP: 192.168.0.1:

```
x = 0
while x < 10:
    print(x)
    x += 1
```

code2.py on computer2, IP: 192.168.0.2:

```
y = {'r': 4, 'l': 7, 'm': 3}

if min(y.values())>=3:
    print True
else:
    print None
```

Comment: There are multiple ways to achieve this. You could run a web server and then connect to that server with python. Then wait for the server to send something to trigger the codes. Could be just clicking a button on your phone.

Comment: could you give me some hints, please?

Comment: There exists a python module called socket. I've seen some youtubers use it and have no experience with it. I don't really know how to setup a simple server to work with sockets, but I'm sure there is plenty of help online on how to do that.

Comment: @ Maxxik CZ thanks for your help.